# Use VBA tp Export each tab in Excel file as PDF with each tab's name separately

Tags: vba, excel

I have following VBA code to help me to save each tabs in my excel file as PDF files separately.
The only question I have is how can I name my exported PDF files same as the tabs name in original excel.

For example, I have two tabs in my excel, with names 1234 and 4321 according, after I saved them as PDF, I hope I have tow PDFs, one's name is 1234 and another one is 4321.

```
 Option Explicit

Sub createPDFfiles()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim mypath As String
    mypath = ActiveWorkbook.path
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next 'Continue if an error occurs

        Fname = mypath & ws.Index & "_result"

        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=Fname, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Fname = mypath & ws.Name`?

Comment: You will need to include a backslash... like this: `Fname = mypath & "\" & ws.Index & "_result.pdf"`

Comment: It's worthy to have a look on ["Check if a certain pdf is open and close it"]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283705/use-vba-tp-export-each-tab-in-excel-file-as-pdf-with-each-tabs-name-separately before you are going to create a possibly already existing file and do this check before. Thx @Siddharth Rout

Comment: it works, i used:  Fname = mypath & "\" & ws.Name